# Parse JSON data with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am having below JSON data which I would like to parse with GSON libray. Having small issue in it and need some guidance from the experts.

```
{"Values":{"Items":[{"Key":"LastUpdateLabel","Value":"Last Update"}]}}

public class Values {
    private List<Item> Items;

    /**
     * @return the items
     */
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return Items;
    }

    /**
     * @param items
     *            the items to set
     */
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        Items = items;
    }

}

final Values val = new Gson().fromJson(res, Values.class);
List<Item> items = val.getItems();
Log.i(TAG, "Val size = " + items.size());

if (items != null && !items.isEmpty()) {
    for (Item item : items) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Key = " + item.getKey());
        Log.i(TAG, "Value = " + item.getValue());
    }
}
```

But its not working. Can anyone help me to understand this as I am new to GSON.

Comment: I am getting NullPointer Exception while accessing the list of items. Basically its not parsing the JSON data..

Comment: if Gson couldn't parse that string it will throw an exception, maybe you are catching that exception without warning.

Comment: post the exact response, and the exception that you get for json parsing from gson, the NPE would come after all that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another class which will contain `values` field:

```
public class JsonData {
    private Values values;
}

public class Values {
    private List<Item> items;
}

public class Item {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

To parse the Json, I'm using Gson created with `FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`, so I can use Java naming convention for variable names:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();

JsonData val = gson.fromJson(res, JsonData.class);
```

If you don't want to use `FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` then chane varlible names to `String Key`, `String Value` etc. But I think it is better to follow Java naming convention.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Its working. A very quick question, can you please kindly explain me why I need 3rd class? Is it because its having Values as Json object and then Items and then array?

Comment: @Scorpion You could have many other keys at the same level as `Values` key, like `Values1`, `Values2`, `Values3` etc. So at first Gson looked for `Values` variable to save there the `Values` object, but you didn't have variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I'm using com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory

```
public static Object parseClass(Class clazz, String object) {
    try {
        GsonFactory instance = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        return instance.fromString(object, clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.loge(TAG, "Error while parsing JSON object");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know alot about gson/json, but i've tried implementation of such parsing:

```
public static List<LevelModel> getLevels(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<LevelModel> levels;

    String levelsJson = Gdx.files.internal("data/world/levels.json").readString();
    levels = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(levelsJson, LevelModel[].class));

    return levels;
}
```